# Sql select doesnt give results, but the table is not empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this sql select:

```
$sql = "SELECT
  datum,
  COUNT(rendeles_id) AS ennyi
FROM
  rendeles_adatok
WHERE
  datum >= $date_start AND(
    datum <= $date_end AND STATUS = $ rendeles_allapot
  )
GROUP BY
  datum
ORDER BY
  datum ASC";
```

When i print it out, the sql looks like:

```
SELECT
  datum,
  COUNT(rendeles_id) AS ennyi
FROM
  rendeles_adatok
WHERE
  datum >= 2017 -09 -01 AND(
    datum <= 2017 -09 -30 AND STATUS = 0
  )
GROUP BY
  datum
ORDER BY
  datum ASC
```

The problem is, that I don't get any results. If I type in 2017-09-01 for start date, and 2017-09-30 for end date, that don't give anything.

I show you on this photo, that my table isn't empty. The datum field is a date type.
[image]

Comment: Dates are strings, you should put quotes around them like so: `'2017-09-01'`.

Comment: Strings? I store them in a date type field.

Comment: Just try it... :-) Or read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: you can use `STR_TO_DATE($date_start, '%Y-%m-%d')` and `STR_TO_DATE($date_end, '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: `WHERE datum >= '$date_start'` ... but you should be using prepared statements.  Voting to close as a typo question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I doubt this is a typo - it's rather the OP not knowing they need to let the SQL engine know this is a single value, not an expression to be evaluated. Ideally through use of parameters, as you wrote.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: How can you write an answer with a prepared statement? The question doesn't tell us which MySQL interface is being used? PDO? MySQLi? Or, even MySQL?

Comment: The second one! Mysqli

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$sql = "ELECT datum, 
       Count(rendeles_id) AS ennyi 
FROM   rendeles_adatok 
WHERE  datum >= '$date_start' 
AND    ( 
              datum <= '$date_end' 
       AND    status = '$rendeles_allapot)                     
GROUP BY datum ORDER BY datum ASC";
```

Comment: Use prepared statements please.

Comment: It works, thanks. The problem was what @KIKO Software writed in the first comment, the missing quotes. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Webshop2229 While just using quotes works, it's a dangerous technique. If you use them you're probably in for some [trouble](https://xkcd.com/327/) in future. I suggest you explore the possibility to use parameterized statements (see discussion under the post).